# Can I get div's background-image url?

Tags: jquery, url, html, background-image

I have a button of which when I click it I want to alert the `background-image` URL of `#div1`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get URL from background-image Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397529/get-url-from-background-image-property)

Answer (score 203, accepted):

I usually prefer `.replace()` to regular expressions when possible, since it's often easier to read: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/z2jKA/2

```
    $("div").click(function() {
        var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
        bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "");
        alert(bg);
    });
```

Comment: What if the background image URL is something like `url(my%20picture%20Copy\(1\).jpg)`? Your replace cause the bg variable to be `my%20picture%20Copy\(1\.jpg)`. It also doesn't strip quoting (e.g. `url("the picture.jpg")`).

Comment: Then you'll either have to add some code to un-escape the `%20` and parentheses, or ask yourself if you really needed them there in the first place. If quoting in an issue, use [RobW](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8809891/901048)'s solution instead.

Comment: Doesn't handle multiple background images as a possibility.

Comment: @Marcel Easy if you just have images; just split the string on commas. Trickier if you have things like [linear gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds) in there, since those also have commas.

Comment: `var bg = $(this).css('background-image').slice(4).slice(0,-1)` ;)

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox! Take a look at MoMolog for a more complete and cross-browser Regex, that takes in account all the possibilities for "url( [...] )", with single and double quotes.

Comment: this won't work if the background-image is something like `background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.4)), url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png")`

Comment: @glasspill Yes, I already said that when Marcel pointed it out. Something like that requires a more intelligent parser that can split on the correct commas, but OP didn't require such a thing.

Answer (score 55):

Yes, that's possible:

```
$("#id-of-button").click(function() {
    var bg_url = $('#div1').css('background-image');
    // ^ Either "none" or url("...urlhere..")
    bg_url = /^url\((['"]?)(.*)\1\)$/.exec(bg_url);
    bg_url = bg_url ? bg_url[2] : ""; // If matched, retrieve url, otherwise ""
    alert(bg_url);
});
```

Comment: I want to alert it not to set it. Alert or write the path on console.log

Comment: to write on console try : console.log($('#div1').css('background-image'))

Comment: @RobW Thank you. That prints url(google.com) instead of just the domain

Comment: @jQuerybeast My code is not setting the CSS. The `.css` method returns the value of a property, when invoked with one argument.

Comment: Cannot call method match. Shall I turn it into regEx?

Comment: Try: `bg_url = /^url\(['"](.+)["']\)$/.exec(bg_url);`, to be safe.

Comment: Could this be modified so that it can accept a url with or without quotes? At present I get an error if my url is:

url(http://www.example.com/image.jpg)

Comment: @Lopsided Show an example where a background image is loaded through `url` and this method fails. Are you sure that the element you're targeting has a background image? Is it really an external image and not something like a CSS gradient?

Comment: @RobW awe damn I just deleted the script. Sorry, I had to move on anyway. I'll get it going another way.

Comment: @RobW is that faster then `bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');`?

Comment: @tim No, it's just more accurate. Imagine: `background-image: url('photo(2012).png');` With your bit of code, you'll get "'photo(2012.png')", which is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 22):

I have slightly improved answer, which handles extended CSS definitions like:

```
background-image: url(http://d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/359de8f/images/shared/noise-1.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(81, 127, 164), rgb(48, 96, 136))
```

JavaScript code:

```
var bg = $("div").css("background-image")
bg = bg.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '')
```

Result:

```
"http://d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/359de8f/images/shared/noise-1.png"
```

Comment: this won't work if the background-image is something like background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.4)), url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png")

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned already, Blazemongers solution is failing to remove quotes (e.g. returned by Firefox). Since I find Rob Ws solution to be rather complicated, adding my 2 cents here:

```
$('#div1').click (function(){
  url = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/^url\(['"]?/,'').replace(/['"]?\)$/,'');
  alert(url);
})
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm using this one

```
  function getBackgroundImageUrl($element) {
    if (!($element instanceof jQuery)) {
      $element = $($element);
    }

    var imageUrl = $element.css('background-image');
    return imageUrl.replace(/(url\(|\)|'|")/gi, ''); // Strip everything but the url itself
  }
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I think that using a regular expression for this is faulty mainly due to

- The simplicity of the task
- Running a regular expression is always more cpu intensive/longer than cutting a string.

Since the *url("* and *")* components are constant, trim your string like so:

```
$("#id").click(function() {
     var bg = $(this).css('background-image').trim();
     var res = bg.substring(5, bg.length - 2);
     alert(res);
});
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution. But this doesn't work in Safari. With this approach you get "ttps://.....jp" instead of "https://.....jpg"..

Comment: I believe the `"`s are optional in this syntax. `url(myimg.jpg)` works fine here.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple regex which will remove the `url("` and `")` from the returned string.

```
var css = $("#myElem").css("background-image");
var img = css.replace(/(?:^url\(["']?|["']?\)$)/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just one call to `replace` (regex version):

`var bgUrl = $('#element-id').css('background-image').replace(/url\(("|')(.+)("|')\)/gi, '$2');`

Answer (score 0):

My two cents.
None of these solutions work if the ***background-image*** property is overwritten in CSS by the ***background*** property.
Let's say you have the ***background-image*** property set and you don't want to see it in the browser, you just need to get the value in jQuery for some purpose.
So, if you have something like this:

```
<div class="myDivWithBackground">
 <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
<style>
.myDivWithBackground{
 background-image: URL('url-here.jpg')
}
div.myDivWithBackground{
 background: #fff!important
}
</style>
```

Then `$('div').css('background-image');` returns ***none*** instead the URL.

If you need to keep ***background*** white and also to get the *background-image* URL value in jQuery then replace the ***background*** with ***pseudo-element***, like this:

```
<style>
    .myDivWithBackground{
     background-image: URL('url-here.jpg')
    }
    div.myDivWithBackground:after{
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #fff;
      top: 0;
      position: absolute;
    }
    div.myDivWithBackground p{
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9999;
    }
</style>
```

Now `$('div').css('background-image');` returns ***URL('url-here.jpg')*** instead ***none***.