# How to read background image URL with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

How could I get the background image url of `#aboutus` div? I'm trying something like this

```
$('#aboutus').css('background')=='url(primo2.png)'
```

If I console log the first part of the above expression, I get

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(file:///G:/u/primo2.png) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box
```

And I only needed `url()` to compare. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('#aboutus').css('background-image')`

Comment: `$('#aboutus').css('background').indexOf('url(primo2.png)')` note that firefox adds quotes to the filename while chrome doesn't.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus please add it as an answer.

Comment: @Darmen I was hoping to see this closed before anyone answered below yet still give OP a quick answer :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think you are looking for this-**

```
$(function() {
    $("div").click(function() {
        var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
        bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
        alert(bg);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/z2jKA/2/

Actual answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8810040/2300749

Comment: That's it. Thank you. (It would be more ethical if you attributed the author next time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809876/can-i-get-divs-background-image-url )