# Jquery: how to get length of background-image style attribute?

Tags: jquery, string-length

I need to get the length of an inline style background-image source, eg:

```
<div id="imageholder" style="background-image: url(image.jpg)">
```

Length would be 9

I have tried:

```
$('#imageholder').css('background-image').length;
```

But I cant seem to get it working.

Would anyone know the proper way of getting this length?

Comment: The length of the string...? Why do you need this? Also, it's `.length`, not `.lenght`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$('#imageholder').css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace(')','').length;
```

**[regex used from Blazemonger answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8810040/1719752)**

Comment: Finally one who notice that `url()` would be returned too!

Comment: Wouldn't `$('#imageholder').css('background-image').length - 5` be easier...?