# How to detect the url of an image in a div and append it to another div HTML

Tags: jquery, css, html, image

I was wondering how to use jQuery to find the url of a `div`s `background-image` and append it to another `div`. How can I do this?

Comment: do you have your work so far, or some sample code we can look at?

Comment: check this one.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809876/can-i-get-divs-background-image-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bg = $('#source').css('backgroundImage')
$('#target').css('backgroundImage', bg)
```

You can also do it easily without jQuery:

```
var bg = document.getElementById('source').style.backgroundImage
document.getElementById('target').style.backgroundImage = bg
```

If you only want the url *content* of the property:

```
var re = /url\((.+)\)/  // assuming the format: url(/path/to/image.png)
var bg = $('#source').css('backgroundImage')
var url = re.exec(bg)[1]
$('#target').css('backgroundImage', url)
```

Comment: Oh. Ha! Didn't even think of that! Thanks!