# How to get reference to the background image?

Tags: javascript

How can I get reference to the `background image` object (or reference to it as a *node*) in JavaScript?

```
var backgroundImgObject = document. .... ?
```

Based on this reference, is it possible to get URL of the background image? Any other ways to get URL?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809876/can-i-get-divs-background-image-url) will help.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch the background Image

```
var img = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
// Will return url('anyimage.png')

var img = document.body.style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);
// Will return anyimage.png
```

Set the background Image

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('anyimage.png')";
```

In more genral way `document.body` can be replaced with any `DOM object`

Comment: What if I need to return URL, not to set it? How can I retrieve it?

Comment: Is it document.body.style.backgroundImage.src ?

Comment: Use `document.body.style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1)`, see updated answer.