# How to get the background url of the image using the javascript or selenium

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium

I'm trying to get the background url of the image. below is the code from the webpage

```html
<style type="text/css">
             .great-banner.live-banner { 
             background-image:
                 url("urloftheimage");
             }
            </style>
   <div class="great-banner live-banner">
   </div>
```

I tried using

document.getElementsByClassName(".great-banner.live-banner").style.backgroundimage

window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName(".great-banner.live-banner"),false); but both of these didn't work form me

I also tried

window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('.great-banner.live-banner')[0], null).getPropertyValue('background-image').split(/'|"/)[1]; and i'm getting the below error

Error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Can you please help me how to get the background image URL

Comment: Try using style.backgroundImage (note the capital i in image)

Comment: I tried it and got this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundImage' of undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get div's background-image url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809876/can-i-get-divs-background-image-url)

Answer (score 1):

First of all `document.getElementsByClassName` will return a collection of elements, so there is no `style` property. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Secondly, the argument you pass to the function should be a class name, not a css selector. Maybe you are looking for `querySelectorAll` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Try `document.querySelectorAll(".great-banner.live-banner")[0].style.backgroundImage` instead

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

`window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('great-banner live-banner')[0], null).getPropertyValue('background-image').split(/'|\"/)[1]; in java script. It will return the URL.`

While using in selenium:

`JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsExec.executeScript("return window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('great-banner live-banner')[0], null).getPropertyValue('background-image').split(/'|\"/)[1];"));`

Add 'return' in the script as per the above line while using in selenium otherwise, it will provide null value