# Jquery if statement for background image not working

Tags: jquery

I have the condition:

```
console.log(jQuery(".sl-slide:visible .bg-img").css("background-image"));

if(jQuery(".sl-slide:visible .bg-img").css("background-image") == "url(http://pacificolife.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/bw1-1.jpg)")
{
    console.log("Here");
}
```

but when the background is equal to that url, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems a thing you can simply solve by *debugging*. Learn how to do it, and you'll help yourself in the future.

Comment: It won't work ..

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because those are not the same strings:

`var background = jQuery(".sl-slide:visible .bg-img").css("background-image"))`

If you do that, `background` will have the value of `url("http://pacificolife.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/bw1-1.jpg")`

No matter if on your css file, you write:

```
.sl-slide:visible .bg-img {
  /* with '' */
  background-image: url("http://pacificolife.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/bw1-1.jpg");
  /* without '' */
  background-image: url(http://pacificolife.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/bw1-1.jpg);
}
```

The output will always be the same.

**Solutions**:

1. Do the comparsion with the *exact same string*.
2. Remove the URL(). Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010803/4283493):

Code:

```
var bg = jQuery(".sl-slide:visible .bg-img").css("background-image")); 
var url = bg.replace(/(?:^url\(["']?|["']?\)$)/g, "");
console.log(url === 'http://pacificolife.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/bw1-1.jpg');
// true
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xjfutxu/8/)