# getElementsByTagName is not returning all the images why?

Tags: javascript, dom, web-crawler

I'm trying to get all the img element from some website.
I opened the chrome dev tools console and put the following code which is,

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
console.log(imgs[i]);
}
```

Yes, code works and returns lists of images in console but not fully.
I noticed that some img elements are not returned.

the parts that is not returened is in the following image.(the links is [here](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.0.0.2603e18a4AeWvZ&id=631883901740&ns=1#detail))
I really wonder why these guys are not returned. Why is that?
[image]

Comment: Because those aren't `<img>` elements, those are `<a>` with a background image. Inspect those element and you'll see that they are something like `<a style="background:url(...)">`

Comment: You need to give us the actual consoe output...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comment, there are no `<img>` elements, those are `<a>` elements with a css background image.

If you want to get those image urls, simply select the `<a>` elements, access their `background-image` css property and extract the urls:

```
var aElems = document.querySelectorAll(".J_Prop_Color a");
var images = [];

for(var i = 0; i < aElems.length; i++) {
  images.push(aElems[i].style.backgroundImage.replace("url(", "").replace(")", "").replace(/\"/gi, ""))
}

console.log(images);
```

The `.replace("url(", "").replace(")", "").replace(/\"/gi, "")` part is used to remove the surrounding `url("...")` as per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8810040/9867451).

**Note 1:** The resulting urls appear to be [protocol-relative urls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4071117/9867451), where they start with `//` rather than an explicit protocol like `https://`, you may want to prepend `"https:"` to them before using them.

**Note 2:** The resulting urls are of thumbnails rather than of the full-sized images, remove the `_(number)x(number).jpg` part of those urls by using this replace: `replace(/_\d+x\d+\.[^.]+$/, "")` to get the full-size image urls:

```
images.push("https:" + aElems[i]
  .style.backgroundImage
  .replace("url(", "").replace(")", "").replace(/\"/gi, "")
  .replace(/_\d+x\d+\.[^.]+$/, "")
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment ibrahim. When I tried this code I got zero length list. But I got the logic. I will try to fix that thank you again!

Comment: @JunhoLee that's probably because you are running that bit of code before the images get populated. Maybe wait for the document to load first.

Comment: @JunhoLee oops, it should be `querySelectorAll` rather than `querySelector`, my bad, sorry

Answer (score 1):

The problem if you open the console and inspect the elements is like someone mention in the comments that there are no image tags, if you check the console, you will see:
a div.

You want to do:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByID(IDVALUES);
var i;
for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
console.log(imgs[i]);
}
```

the id is stored in the div id something like 'ks-component-??'

Most likely the answer above will not give you want since you want multiple images you would want to create an array and push the corresponding elements to it.

```
var img1 = ....
var img2 = etc....
....
let arr = [];
arr.push(img1);
arr.push(img2);
....
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Where the ... means the list or all the variables you need