# Can I get background-image source's size by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

always thanks for everyone of stackoverflow

I made a div and it includes background-image: url(imageURL) such like this codes

```
HTML >
<div ref={mapRef} className="image-container" style={{ backgroundPosition: '0 0' }} >
    {markersState}
</div>
```

```
CSS >
.image-container {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;

  cursor: grab;
  user-select: none;

  background-image: url("/images/map.png");
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I want to get background-image source(='/images/map.png')'s size
How can I get it? (source's width: 2907px, height: '3460px')

if I need to use  instead of background-image, that solution can be good for me
Also, is there good library, recommend me please

Thank you, have a nice day

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Good question! But repeated; hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Comment: @blanknamefornow thanks a lot but both returns 52(:number) the image source's width is 2907px

Comment: The background image would need to be rendered in as data to see these values and if they appear incorrect its due to spoofing of the images EXIF/HEADERS which is a different thing. In production we don't worry about this, we resize all images to our clouds and CDN it to nearest user the respectful resolutions (fixed). Bandwidth means/etc.

Comment: @Phix I've checked all attributes but there is no image source's width or height

Comment: @blanknamefornow sorry, I consoled wrong. when I console img.clientWidth, it returns 1024 which is div width. I think there is no .png HEADER problem..

Comment: If you put the image into an img element you should be able to get the image's natural height and width - once it has loaded - can you give us the url to the actual image in your code.

Comment: @AHaworth yea 'naturlWidth' worked thank you very much! I really love stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the actual width and height of a background image then you can follow these steps

Get the background image's URL like this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010803/1391805)

```
var css = document.getElementById("myElem").style.backgroundImage;
var img = css.replace(/(?:^url\(["']?|["']?\)$)/g, "");
```

Once you have the image URL do this

```
var newImg = new Image();
newImg.onload = function(e) {
   console.log( this.naturalWidth ); // This is the width you are looking for
   console.log( this.naturalHeight ); // .. similarly the height.
}
newImg.src = "img.jpg";
```

Given the fact that this loads an image first you may want to use this carefully, if this is something that does not apply for a lot of images on a single page then this may not be a performance degrade but if the scale is larger then you may consider something better than loading an image on the client side to fetch its actual dimension.